# ColorFunction with the function of luminance

Tags: plotting, color

I want to have a `DensityPlot` or `ListDensityPlot`, whose color function is a rainbow but whose luminance is given by another function. For example, I've attached an image of a vortex, whose color function shows the phase and its luminance shows the intensity. In the following plot, you can use `F1 =  ArcTan[x,y]` function with luminance `F2 = (x^2+y^2)*Exp[-x^2-y^2]`.

[image: my example]

Comment: Could you show the complete code that generated the image you showed?

Comment: You've seen `Hue[]`, right?

Comment: Yes I sow it, but I can use that only for Plot3D (see Below the code). I want the same dependence but for DensityPlot and more for ListDensityPlot.
Plot3D[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[Rescale[ArcTan[x, y], {-Pi, Pi}]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

#### Table Case

> Kuba, can you add also a solution for tables instead of functions, because in fact I have something like this: `table1 = Table[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]`, `table2 = Table[ArcTan[x, y], {x, -2.999, 3}, {y, -3., 3}]`
>
> – Mushegh

```
{
    table1 = Table[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, ##}, {y, ##}],
    table2 = Table[Arg[x + I y], {x, ##}, {y, ##}]
} & @@ {-3, 3, .2};

Image[
  Reverse[#, 2] & @ Transpose @ MapThread[
    {(#2 - Pi/2.)/Pi, 1, # E } &,
    ArrayResample[#, {500, 500}] & /@ N[{table1, table2}],
    2
  ],
  ColorSpace -> "HSB"
]
```

[image]

You have probably noticed a strange "outflow". That is because of the interpolation of positive "x" axis neighborhood for `ArcTan[x,y]`:

```
table2 // ListPlot3D
```

[image]

Here is a fix:

```
res = ArrayResample[N@#, {500, 500}, ##2] &;
Image[
 Reverse[#, 2] &@Transpose@MapThread[
    {Which[#3 > 0, ArcSin[#2], #2 > 0, ArcCos[#2] + Pi/2, True, 
         ArcCos[#2] - 3 Pi/2]/Pi - 1/2., 1, # E} &,
    {
     res@table1,
     res[Sin@table2],
     res[Cos@table2]
     },
    2
    ],
 ColorSpace -> "HSB"
 ]
```

[image]

---

#### Functions case

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -#, #}, {y, -#, #},
     ColorFunction        -> Function[{x, y, u, v},
        Directive[
           Opacity[E (x^2 + y^2)*Exp[-x^2 - y^2]], (*E - scaling factor*)
           Hue[(ArcTan[x, y] - Pi/2)/Pi]
        ]
     ],
     PlotPoints           -> 100,
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
     Axes                 -> False,
     Frame                -> False,
     Background           -> Black,
     BoundaryStyle        -> None,
     ImageSize            -> {Automatic, 300},
     Mesh                 -> None
     ] &@3

barLegend = ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, .1}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   ColorFunction    -> (Hue[#2] &), 
   AspectRatio      -> 10, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, 
   FrameTicks       -> {{False, {0, 2 Pi}}, {False, False}}, 
   BaseStyle        -> 24,
   FrameLabel       -> {{None, "Phase"}, {None, None}}, 
   ImageSize        -> {Automatic, 300},
   Mesh             -> None
]


Grid[{{plot, barLegend}}]
```

[image]

Comment: the "BaseStyle" and "Ticks" are not working. Is it problem of Mathematica version I have? it is Mathematica 9.0

Comment: Also the color bar is discrete colors from orange to red

Comment: @Mushegh I've changed BarLegend so Ticks should be correct now. What do you mean in your second comment?

Comment: @Mushegh, `Hue[0]` and `Hue[1]` are both red.

Comment: Now it is working, I have added "Mesh-> None", because it was bringing some mesh on the plot. Thanks

Comment: @Kuba, can you add also a solution for tables instead of functions, because in fact I have something like this: table1 = Table[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
table2 = Table[ArcTan[x, y], {x, -2.999, 3}, {y, -3., 3}]

Comment: If I am trying to use interpolation and after your option, the plots are loosing the quality.

Comment: I know, because I have generated them. In my actual problem the function is very long and working slow, that's why it is faster for me to generate once the table1 and table2 data on the area -a<x<a and -a<y<a. And then continue all my calculations with that table1 and table2 datas.

Comment: I have some solution, but I don't know how much it is correct:

Plot1 = ListDensityPlot[table1, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
Plot2 = ListDensityPlot[table2, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "GreenTones"];
ImageMultiply[Plot1, Plot2]

Comment: I meant "GrayTones" instead of "GreenTones"

Comment: Thanks. Can you please offer something equivalent to ArrayResample? because in my version it is not working.

Comment: @Mushegh I'm offering `Interpolation + Array` but you have to adjust arguments properly.

Answer (score 2):

No legend for this slight simplification of Kuba's proposal, but it can be easily added if desired:

```
RegionPlot[True, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Background -> Black, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
           ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[(Arg[x + I y] - Pi/2)/Pi, 1, 1,
                                                 (x^2 + y^2) Exp[1 - x^2 - y^2]]], 
           ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 95]
```

[image: it does look a bit hypnotic]

Comment: Thank you for short solution, 
can you add also a solution for tables instead of functions, because in fact I have something like this: table1 = Table[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}] table2 = Table[ArcTan[x, y], {x, -2.999, 3}, {y, -3., 3}]

Comment: If I am trying to use interpolation and after your option, the plots are loosing the quality.

Comment: @Mush, *why did you **not** post that problem to begin with*?!

Comment: In the begining I thougth that knowing the solution for functions is enough, because I can after interpolate the data to a function, but then I have tried it and sow that the quality is very bad by interpolation option

Comment: Actually I have this option, can you comment to it?

Comment: Plot1 = ListDensityPlot[table1, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]; Plot2 = ListDensityPlot[table2, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "GreenTones"]; ImageMultiply[Plot1, Plot2]